# Need to send mail using batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have the below code that gives me 2 values.

1. First is the most recently modified directory based on some ext file (test.mtc)
2. Second is taking the name of that (test.mtc) file and adding the domain to send mail. For eg test.companyname.com

I was able to achieve this with the below batch file but now I need to send mail using the output of this batch file. Using blat is it doable?

Below is the script I wrote in my batch file
Output.bat

```
cd C:\Desktop\Foldername
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d *.mtc') do echo User=%%~na@companyname.com >> Output.txt
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('dir /a:d /b /o:d') do set recent=%%x
echo Path=\\Mycomputername\Desktop\FolderName\%recent% >> Output.txt
```

I need to use these values and send mail using batch file. something like below
-- send to  from  subject test complete body

Answer (score 2):

You can send email using native VBS scripting, using this batch file.

```
:: email.bat :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
@echo off
setlocal

:: use these settings to send from a gmail account
:: set port=465 and set SSL=True

:: use these settings for standard email SMTP port and no encryption
:: set port=25 and set SSL=False

:: Change these following items to use the same variables all the time
:: or use the command line to pass all the variables

set Port=25
set SSL=False
set From="myemail@myemailserver.com"
set To="recipient@server.com"
set Subject="Subject line"
set Body="Email Body in one line"
set SMTPServer="mailservername.myemailserver.com"
set User="username"
set Pass="password"
set fileattach="d:\myfolder\file.txt"


:: This section sets the command line arguments
:: use this format:  CALL email.bat "myname@gmail.com" "RecipientEmailAddress@server.com" "Subject line" "Email Body in one line" "smtp.gmail.com"  "myname@gmail.com" "password" "d:\folder\filename to attach.txt"


if "%~7" NEQ "" (
set From="%~1"
set To="%~2"
set Subject="%~3"
set Body="%~4"
set SMTPServer="%~5"
set User="%~6"
set Pass="%~7"
set fileattach="%~8"
)

set "vbsfile=%temp%\email-bat.vbs"
del "%vbsfile%" 2>nul
set cdoSchema=http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration
echo >>"%vbsfile%" Set objArgs       = WScript.Arguments
echo >>"%vbsfile%" Set objEmail      = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
echo >>"%vbsfile%" objEmail.From     = %From%
echo >>"%vbsfile%" objEmail.To       = %To%
echo >>"%vbsfile%" objEmail.Subject  = %Subject%
echo >>"%vbsfile%" objEmail.Textbody = %body%
if exist %fileattach% echo >>"%vbsfile%" objEmail.AddAttachment %fileattach%
echo >>"%vbsfile%" with objEmail.Configuration.Fields
echo >>"%vbsfile%"  .Item ("%cdoSchema%/sendusing")        = 2 ' not local, smtp
echo >>"%vbsfile%"  .Item ("%cdoSchema%/smtpserver")       = %SMTPServer%
echo >>"%vbsfile%"  .Item ("%cdoSchema%/smtpserverport")   = %port%
echo >>"%vbsfile%"  .Item ("%cdoSchema%/smtpauthenticate") = 1 ' cdobasic
echo >>"%vbsfile%"  .Item ("%cdoSchema%/sendusername")     = %user%
echo >>"%vbsfile%"  .Item ("%cdoSchema%/sendpassword")     = %pass%
echo >>"%vbsfile%"  .Item ("%cdoSchema%/smtpusessl")       = %SSL%
echo >>"%vbsfile%"  .Item ("%cdoSchema%/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 30
echo >>"%vbsfile%"  .Update
echo >>"%vbsfile%" end with
echo >>"%vbsfile%" objEmail.Send

cscript.exe /nologo "%vbsfile%"
echo email sent (if variables were correct)
del "%vbsfile%" 2>nul
goto :EOF
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the script. Is it possible to use blat utility to send mail?

Comment: Yes, it is.  Blat should work fine, as well as the Sendmail utility.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before, you can use Blat. Example :

```
set eMailTo=someone1@something.com,someone2@something.com
set eMailFrom=randomName
set subj=-s "Email subject"
set eMailBody=*:\******\log.txt
set server=-server SERVERNAME
blat %eMailBody% -to %eMailTo% -f %eMailFrom% %subj% %server%
```