# Send mail through bat script / Unicode implement

Tags: email, batch-file, cmd, vbscript, send

about previous old post named "[Need to send mail using batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23170978/need-to-send-mail-using-batch-file)" by User: [@3438791](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3438791/user3438791)
and written code below by respectful member [@foxidrive](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2299431/foxidrive),
need to implement Unicode set in Body of an E-mail, also in Subject if it is possible.
I´ve also prepared my calling "1".bat, "2".bat, ..etc.. files to have UTF-8 role.

So I added UTF-8 code in line after; and in body of massage tekst added:

```
<p>some text</p> or <b>some text</b>.


.
...
set UTF="utf-8"
.
...
....

echo >>"%vbsfile%" Set objArgs       = WScript.Arguments
echo >>"%vbsfile%" Set objEmail      = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
echo >>"%vbsfile%" objEmail.From     = %From%
echo >>"%vbsfile%" objEmail.To       = %To%
echo >>"%vbsfile%" objEmail.Subject  = %Subject%
echo >>"%vbsfile%" objEmail.HTMLBody = %body%
echo >>"%vbsfile%" objEmail.HTMLBodyPart.Charset = %UTF%

...
..
.
```

Tried also with:

```
.    
..
echo >>"%vbsfile%" objEmail.Textbody = %body%
echo >>"%vbsfile%" objEmail.TextBodyPart.Charset = %UTF%
..
.
```

so output of a "%vbsfile%"  ---> "temp" has those line needed for interpreter.
But obviously this doesn't work.

So need please help ...
Thanks

Comment: This code appears to be correct. How do you know it "isn't working?"

Comment: I would suggest that the issue is that you're passing characters which are not in the current codepage of cmd.exe to the vbscript, and those are not therefore correct when they get into the file. Instead of just showing the code you used, it would therefore make more sense, if you instead open `%vbsfile%`, in your chosen viewing application and see if your characters were written to it correctly. If they were there is nothing to 'fix', as your code is correct, if they weren't you should look at using a more appropriate codepage in your batch file. `chcp /?` should help you with the syntax.

Comment: Why use a bat file to create the vbscript? Why can't it just be a vbscript?

Comment: Regards @SomethingDark, it suppose to work, but it doesn't I don't know why, all variables is passed by to vbsfile temp variable correctly but It seems to get ascii characters in subject and body.

Comment: Re.,g @Compo, 
yes, there are passed: objEmail.TextBody = "...šđčćž ŠĐČĆŽ ......... !" exactly. Yes I´ve put cmd.exe --> autorun at 56001 UTF character view, but I am assume that is window code page only not in the system, Am I correct ?

Comment: Why use a bat file to create ..... Reg.   @Squashman   Because I have more that 1.bat to call of different conetnt, so it is very easy to use in this way.... VBS is more complicated to do.... at least for me ! thanks !

Comment: If the content of your VBScript is correct, then, _as I've already said_, the issue is not with the code. The issue is in researching why the `HTMLBodyPart.Charset = utf-8` is not functioning. For that you should rewrite your question, removing completely the batch file references, as those are irrelevant to the issue you're reporting. It's easier to write a VBScript file directly and run it from a batch file using wscript.exe or cscript.exe, than it is to write a VBScript file from a batch file, complete with escapes etc. and then run it using the same wscript.exe or cscript.exe executable.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, I will try to do that, it seems that is culprit for using UTF-8 in that way (VBS in batch.) Thanks @Compo.